# System.NullReferenceException Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at i++

Tags: c#, null, nullreferenceexception

I'd like to read every 2nd variable from `result[]` to questions.

```
string[] questionstr = null;
int ii = 0;
for (int i = 0; result.Length > i;)
{
  questionstr[ii] = result[i];
  ii = ii+1;
  i = i+2;
}
```

it gives me `System.NullReferenceException` at `ii=ii+1;` I tried `ii++;` too but same error.

Comment: In particular, read under the heading ***More Specifically***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `NullReferenceException` must be from the line above:

```
questionstr[ii] = result[i];
```

Your array `questionStr` isn't initialized. Trying to use it is causing the exception.

You should initialize it before using it, like this:

```
string[] questionStr = new string[result.Length];
```

so that the array size is large enough to hold all your results

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize the string array questionstr as following:

```
 var questionStr = new string[result.Length/2+1];
```